# Passing a js var into a solidity function

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

Wrote a function in solidity which is like this,

```
function AddData(uint _index, string _projectName, string _devAddress, string _developer) public {
    Datas[_index] = Data(_index, 0, _projectName, _devAddress, _developer);
}
```

Note that this is just a fragment of the whole solidity code. In js, i'm trying to pass variables into the functions but doesnt seem to be working. I assume it's the js variables unable to pass into solidity string variables.

```
counterDB.AddData(id_db, projectName, devAddress, developer, function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
         console.log('Error: ' + err);
     }
     else {
         console.log(result);
     }
});
```

The variables passed in are data i pulled out from the database to pass into the smart contract. I checked every data has been pulled in properly but i cant pass the data into the function. Am i missing a function to convert the var into string?

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" What exactly happens? Do you see an error message? If so, what? If not, what were you expecting to happen and what actually happened?

Comment: i tried call the get functions but nothing comes out. if i hard coded the data into the parameters and call the get function it'll work. But i managed to solve it after asking the question.. Put the variables into a String(). eg: String(projectName)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using web3 v1.0 ? Have you tried to pass the function like this:

```
var yourContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);
const contractFunction = yourContract.methods.AddData(id_db, projectName, devAddress, developer);
const functionBytes = contractFunction.encodeABI();

const rawTx = {
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(200000),
    to: contractAddress,
    from: addressFrom,
    data: functionBytes
    };

web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTx, privateKey)
    .then(RLPencodedTx => {

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(RLPencodedTx['rawTransaction'])
    .on('error', error => { callback(null, error) })
    .on('receipt', receipt => { callback(receipt) });

})
```

Keep in mind, that you have to decrypt the private key if you are using the json export of it:

```
var path = process.cwd();
const exportedAccountString = fs.readFileSync(path + '/your_key_file.json').toString();
const decrypted = web3.eth.accounts.decrypt(exportedAccountString, 'YourPasswordHere...');
const privateKey = decrypted.privateKey;
```